# Increase size of SVG without CSS

Tags: php, html, css, svg

I have the following SVG file, which includes a polyline

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg 
    width="280"
    height="280"
    viewBox="0 0 140 140"
    stroke="blue"
    fill="none">
<polyline points="21,14 18,14 15,7 10,17 7,11 5,14 3,14" />
</svg>
```

The original size is 48x48px, I'm trying to increase the total scale of the SVG to 280x280px (before I send it off to be rendered to a PNG).

**I've tried to increase the width, height and viewBox parameters, however the polylines are obviously not sized along. Is there any way of doing this?**

Comment: I would use this viewBox instead: viewBox="3 7 18 10"

Comment: That does the trick, care to explain and create an answer for this? Also is this result achievable in a dynamic (with code?) way, since I will have many svg's that will pass this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your example I've added a border to the svg element. Now you can see what is happening. The graphic is tiny compared to the viewport. In order to get it right you need to know the bounding box of the polygon `let bb = document.querySelector("polyline").getBBox();` and use the result for the value of the viewBox

```js
let bb = document.querySelector("polyline").getBBox();
console.log(bb)
```

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg 
    width="280"
    height="280"
    viewBox="0 0 140 140"
    stroke="blue"
    fill="none">
<polyline points="21,14 18,14 15,7 10,17 7,11 5,14 3,14" />
</svg>
```

The bounding box of the polyline is:

```
{
  "x": 3,
  "y": 7,
  "width": 18,
  "height": 10
}
```

I'm using those values to build the new value of the viewBox.

Next comes an example where I'm changing the viewBox to viewBox="3 7 18 10". Please observe that now the svg element have a different aspect ratio. The svg element is square while the viewport have a width of 18 and a height of 10. By default the value of [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) is `xMidYMid` aligning the midpoint Y value of the element's viewBox with the midpoint Y value of the viewport.

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg 
    width="280"
    height="280"
    viewBox="3 7 18 10"
    stroke="blue"
    fill="none">
<polyline points="21,14 18,14 15,7 10,17 7,11 5,14 3,14" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! So to calculate the bounding box I need javascript? Since my svg parsing is happening on the server (php).

Comment: Depends on the SVG.  In the case of this `<polyline>` you don't.  You can see from looking at it what the min and max X coords are (3 & 21), and Y coords (7 & 17).  For other elements, such as a `<path>`, it will be trickier to do with PHP.  But I don't know what sort of SVG parsing libraries are available for PHP.  You could perhaps invoke a separate program written in - for example - C++ that uses a library such as Batik.